# How to get ONLY list of documents in Firebase/Firestore using reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to ask something, i need to fetch data from firebase, BUT only the list of the documents

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNORK.png)

i've already tried, and i'm stuck (at the moment), here's my code:

```
this.ref3 = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("pendatang")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .limit(10);

componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref3.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate2);
  };

onCollectionUpdate2 = (querySnapshot) => {
    const tanggal = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      tanggal.push({
        tanggal: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
      });
    });
    this.setState(
      {
        tanggal,
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.tanggal);
      }
    );
  };
```

Actually i didn't get error, i got the array but it's like didn't get any, when i use `map`, it didn't appear anything inside the state, this is what i got after the fetch [The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wifv.png)

i tried `map` it:

```
{this.state.tanggal.map((item, key) => (
                        <Chip
                          avatar={<Avatar>M</Avatar>}
                          label={item.tanggal}
                          onClick={() => this.ChipsClicked(24)}
                        />
                      ))}
```

and what i got:

[Nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alPZG.png)

I really need help guys :( and I'm actually very curious about firebase, I really appreciate everyone who wants to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your Firebase console screenshot, the document is displayed **with an italic font** in the Firebase console: this is because this document is only present (in the console) as "container" of one or more sub-collection but it is not a "genuine" document.

If you create a `subDoc1` document directly under a `col1` collection with the full path `doc1/subCol1/subDoc1`, no intermediate documents will be created (i.e. no `doc1` document).

The Firebase console shows this kind of "container" (or "placeholder") in italic in order to "materialize" the hierarchy and allow you to navigate to the `subDoc1` document but `doc1` document **doesn't exist in the Firestore database**.

---

So if we have a `doc1` document under the `col1` collection

```
col1/doc1/
```

and another one `subDoc1` under the `subCol1` (sub-)collection

```
col1/doc1/subCol1/subDoc1
```

... actually, from a technical perspective, they are not at all relating to each other. They just share a part of their paths but nothing else.

You can very well create `subDoc1` **without** creating `doc1`.

Another side effect of this is that if you delete a document, its sub-collection(s) still exist. Again, the subcollection docs are not really linked to the parent document.

---

So, in your case, if you need to have genuine docs in the `pendatang` collection, you need to create them at the same time you create the first subcollection doc.

Also, note that Cloud Firestore has shallow reads: querying for documents in a collection doesn't pull in data from subcollections.

Comment: Hey thank you very much! I'm sorry if i mistaken your answer but did you means that I need to change the structure of my collection?

Comment: I don't know if you need to change your data model, this is a very broad question which depends on several criteria that you didn't share. It mainly depends on your requirements in terms of querying. The aim of my answer is to draw your attention on the fact that the docs under the `pendatang` collection do not exist if you don't create them specifically.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope I did not misunderstand, after I tried to understand your answer, I will try other ways, in fact I made as above is to be able to group because (to my knowledge) in firebase can not use the grupby () function

Comment: Don't forget that Cloud Firestore has shallow reads: querying for documents in a collection doesn't pull in data from subcollections.