# `querysnapshot.forEach` method doesn't iterate

Tags: loops, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to add a collection `notifs` right under each document I get from a query. I got document1, document2 and document3 from the query, so I want to add `notifs` collection under each of all these documents, but the result is that `notifs` collection was added only under document1. The other 2 `notifs` collections were added not under document2 or document3, but from the root, showing its path in Italic. It seems that `querysnapshot.forEach(doc =>` method doesn't iterate. How can I add `notifs` collection under each of all the documents that came from the query, not just 1?
Thank you.
Here's my code;

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var GeoFirestore = require('geofirestore').GeoFirestore;

admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(firestore);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
.document("crews/{crew}/clients/{client}")
.onCreate(async snapshot => {
   try {
     const clientfield = snapshot.data().field;
     const clientgeopoint = snapshot.data().g.geopoint;

     const geocollection = geofirestore.collectionGroup('pros');
     const query = geocollection.near({center: clientgeopoint, radius: 10}).where('field', '==', clientfield);

    const promises = [];
    const querySnapshot = await query.get();
              
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
             const docId = doc.id;
             const uid = doc.data().uid;
                    
             const geonotifs = firestore.collection('crews').doc(uid).collection('pros').doc(docId);
             promises.push(geonotifs.ref.collection('notifs').add({
                'field': clientfield,
                'geopoint': clientgeopoint}));
          }); 
        return Promise.all(promises);
        
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
    }
 })
```

[image]

Comment: looks very strange; could you find out the difference between those two doc varieties (collection added vs not added)? like whether it has empty doc in the tree?

Comment: Thanks, Muthu. It is strange, isn't it? but all these documents have the same firestore structure. Why doesn't `querysnapshot.foreach(doc =>` method apply to all `querysnapshot.docs`, but to only 1 doc?

Comment: You don't show the full code of your Cloud Function, but if the Cf only contains the code shown in your question (and is a background triggered CF) you should return the promise chain: `return query.get().then( querySnapshot => {...}).catch(...);`. Also, what is `query` and how exactly is your CF triggered? I think your CF creates some collections twice at two different levels... Please share the **entire code**.

Comment: @Renaudtarnec. Thanks Renaud, I posted my entire code. Please check it and give me your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your full code, it is not clear why you end having **twice** the same document IDs shown in the console in the `crews` collection.

On one hand we see the ID `fPrxMd....` in italic, which means that the document does not exist in the `crews` collection but is part of the path of a child sub-collection (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62388298/3371862) for more details) and, on the other hand, we see a "genuine" document with the same ID. That's weird... Maybe these are created in a specific order that generates this situation but, again, from your full code, it is not clear to me how this can happen. Maybe other SO members have encounter this case.

What I can see is that you are mixing `then()` and `async/await`, which is not recommended.

You should give a try with the following adapted code and start with an empty `crews` collection. *If it does not work I'll remove this answer.*

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("crews/{crew}/clients/{client}")
    .onCreate(async snapshot => {
        
        try {
            
            const clientfield = snapshot.data().field;
            const clientgeopoint = snapshot.data().g.geopoint;

            const geocollection = geofirestore.collectionGroup('pros');
            const query = geocollection.near({ center: brewgeopoint, radius: 10 }).where('field', '==', clientfield);
            const promises = [];

            const querySnapshot = await query.get();
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                const docId = doc.id;
                const uid = doc.data().uid;

                const geonotifs = firestore.collection('crews').doc(uid).collection('pros').doc(docId).collection('notifs');
                promises.push(geonotifs.add({
                    'field': clientfield, 'geopoint': clientgeopoint
                }));
            });

            return Promise.all(promises);
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }

});
```

Comment: `@Renaud` Thanks for your help, Renaud.