# Firebase and Kotlin: getting the id of a document issues

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an interesting issue while playing with Firebase and Kotlin.

```
val docRef = db.collection("Year")
            .document(DB_year.toString())
            .collection("Month")
            .document((DB_month+1).toString())
            .collection("Day")
            .document(today)
            .collection("write")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

                for(document in result) {
                    println("document_id : " + document.id)
                }

            }
```

If you get the document id with this code, you can get it normally.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk6oE.png)

```
enter code here
```

This code cannot get the document id.

```
        val docRef = db.collection("Year")
            .document(DB_year.toString())
            .collection("Month")
            .document((DB_month+1).toString())
            .collection("Day")
            .get()
```

Why is it like this?

- my firestore collection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk6oE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0aws.png)

Comment: "This code cannot get the document id." => What do you exactly expect to get? Can you share a screenshot of the `Day` collection?

Comment: I add images to the post. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As shown in your Firebase console screenshot above, the documents in the `Day` collection are displayed **with an italic font** in the Firebase console: This is because these documents are only present (in the console) as "container" of one or more sub-collection but **are not genuine documents**.

If you create a document directly under the `write` collection with the full path `Year/docYear1/Month/subDocMonth1/Day/subDcoDay1/write/writeDoc`, no intermediate documents will be created (i.e. no document in the `Month` or `Day` collections).

The Firebase console shows this kind of "container" (or "placeholder") in italic in order to "materialize" the hierarchy and allow you to navigate to the `write` document but the `Day` document doesn't exist in the Firestore database. Hence the empty result for your second query

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62388298/3371862) for more details.

---

Note that if you want to get the parent ids (docs and collections) for a doc in the write collection, you can use the `parent` properties of the [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#parent) and [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#parent).

So you can do something like:

```
db.collection("Year")
        .document(DB_year.toString())
        .collection("Month")
        .document((DB_month+1).toString())
        .collection("Day")
        .document(today)
        .collection("write")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

            for(document in result) {
                println("Day_doc_id : " + document.reference.parent.parent?.id)
            }

        }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. So, is there any way to get the container? Is that code that can retrieve the container?

Comment: Yes, the Day "container". But you can only get its ID since there is no doc. Did you try the code?

Comment: Oh, as a result of just trying several things, I succeeded in receiving the Day container with the following code. println("Day_doc_id: "+ document.reference.parent.parent?.id)

Thank you so much for your answer!!

Comment: If it's okay, can I ask one more question?
The code takes only one container of today, can it also take all of those containers like the Day image?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the id property of the `DocumentReference`. I've adapted the anwser! "can it also take all of those containers like the Day image" => No, not with the current situation, because the Days documents actually **don't exist**, so you cannot query them. You would need to query all their children and get the parent  `DocumentReference` which will cost a lot. If you really need the Days docs, you should **create** them, with for exampel a unique field with the Day value.

Comment: Ah, okay.
I think I got to know Firebase better thanks to you.
Thank you, Mr. Genius