# delete a collection with document and collection again inside (firestore react native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am having trouble deleting on firestore

[image]
[image]

here's my delete

```
var chatId = route.params.number; // +639266825843
var docRef = firestore().collection('ChatRoom').doc(chatId).collection('messages');
docRef.doc(chatId).delete();
```

but everytime i try to delete nothing happens . There's no error at all .

this is how I set that collection

```
firestore().collection('ChatRoom')
.doc(id)
.collection('messages')
.add({...myMsg, createdAt:firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete all the docs of the `messages` (sub)collection, you need to query the collection and delete each document, for example by using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or by using a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes) (containing only deletions)

```
  var chatId = route.params.number; // +639266825843
  var colRef = firestore()
    .collection('ChatRoom')
    .doc(chatId)
    .collection('messages');

  colRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    Promise.all(querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => d.ref.delete()));
  });
```

The [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#docs) property of the `QuerySnapshot` returns an array of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`s.

---

In addition, look at how your `+639266825843` document is displayed in an *italic* font: this means, in the console, that this document is only present as "container" of one or more sub-collection(s) but that it is not a "genuine" document. It does not exist, because you never created it, you only created docs in one of its subcollections. More detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62388298/3371862).

Comment: will this delete only the collection with the `+639266825843` and its subcollection ? because others are also going to use the `ChatRoom` collection sir.

Comment: It will delete all the documents that are in the subcollection `messages` of the "doc" `+639266825843`.

Comment: Will try this one sir . Thank you.

Comment: My problem was solved . I was wondering why it can't delete the collection , now I understand why. Thank you.